# GET request from Google Compute Engine for an API that requires a fixed IP gets denied - why?

Tags: python-2.7, google-compute-engine

I'm writing an app using Python and Flask which I'm trying to deploy to a Google Compute Engine virtual machine. This app needs to make a GET request for an API which requires a token that is associated to an IP address, i.e., the API only authorizes requests coming from the IP addresses provided to it beforehand - and this is the only reason I'm using GCE, since I can set a static IP for it but not for App Engine.

The code I use for the request is the following:

```
import urllib2
import logging

TOKEN = 'Bearer <API token>'
URL = 'https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/leagues'
HEADERS = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'authorization': TOKEN}

req = urllib2.Request(URL, headers=HEADERS)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
logging.info(response)
return response
```

When I test the code in my local machine, it works fine, however, when I upload it to the GCE VM, I can only get the HTTP Error 403, which is the error I would get by trying to make a request from an unauthorized IP address. However, I triple-checked the VM's external static IP and the token associated to it: I am using the correct ones for the request.

My current firewall rules are the ones bellow and I'm not sure if they might be related to the problem or not.

```
Name                   Source tag    Allowed protocols      Target tags         Network
                       IP range      ports 
                       Subnetworks 
default-allow-http      0.0.0.0/0     tcp:80,8080        http-server            default
default-allow-https     0.0.0.0/0     tcp:443            https-server           default
default-allow-icmp      0.0.0.0/0     icmp               Apply to all targets   default
default-allow-internal  10.128.0.0/9  tcp:0-65535,       Apply to all targets   default
                                      udp:0-65535,    
                                      icmp            
default-allow-rdp       0.0.0.0/0     tcp:3389           Apply to all targets   default
default-allow-ssh       0.0.0.0/0     tcp:22             Apply to all targets   default
```

I don't know what could be causing this and I hope someone can help me to find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: How are you authorizing the API request from GCE instance (service account) ? For more information about authorization request visit [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/authorization)

Comment: @Faizan: I'm sorry, it's the first time I'm using Compute Engine and I don't get why my problem is related to the Compute Engine API. Perhaps you misunderstood my problem or maybe I'm not explaining it well enough - or maybe I just didn't understand how to use Compute Engine from the start. I'm making a request to the Clash of Clans API at https://api.clashofclans.com from a program running on a Compute Engine instance. Was it this that you understood?

Comment: @Tom, have you tried it via curl command from GCE VM? does it work? curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "authorization: Bearer <API token>" "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/leagues"

Comment: @Kamran, I tried it via curl and it worked, but now I'm even more puzzled since I thought it was something related to the external IP. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is pretty old, but I remember that the problem mysteriously solved itself a week after Kamran's answer. I forgot to come back to tell this at the time.

I didn't find what was causing the problem, but it doesn't matter anymore as it never happened again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Bearer` is missing on front of your API Key. Generate a key for your GCE VM's external IP address and try the following code on your VM. It worked for me.

```
import urllib2
import logging

TOKEN = 'Bearer <API token>'
URL = 'https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/leagues'
HEADERS = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'authorization': TOKEN}

req = urllib2.Request(URL, headers=HEADERS)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
logging.info(response)
print response
```

Comment: Hello @Kamran, actually I am using `Bearer` in front of it. I have edited the code to show it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: what are you getting as response?